# Comparing two probability

Tags: probability

i have a general question.

Let us assume i have a linear monoton probability density function which defines the probability that there is a specific color (e.g. black)

Now i would like to get the probability value for two specific values. 
The issue is that it is a not a discrete density but a stetic. 
For this i need to pickup a delta which shall obviosuly the same.

example:

```
P1 (x1-delta < x1 < x1 + delta) 
P2 (x2-delta < x2 < x2 + delta)
```

finally i will compare P1 to P2 and tell which is more likely "black"

what kind of delta could be a proper one?

thx

Comment: What does "stetic" mean?

Comment: continous ..sorry..wrong english term.

Comment: More precisely: $\text{contin}\color{red}{u}\text{ous}$.

Comment: thx...yes you are right..sorry  i am not a native speaker

Comment: Maybe you would do $\mathbb{P}(X_1 < X_2)$. I'm not sure what you mean by likely. Are you going to run experiments? For that you could need a statistic.

Comment: hi. the data are from a statistic. the issue is to get a specific value for P i need for a continuos distribution an intervall within i get the probability. and for this is no "rules" to define